# parse json object in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am new in iOS and Swift programming, I am trying to make a method to parse json object

My json is as following

```
{
 status : true;
 data :[
   "url" : "",
   "startDate" : "",
   "endDate" : "",
...
]
}
```

my code in swift is like that

import Foundation

```
class SplashResponse {

    let STATUS              = "status";
    let DATA                = "data";

    let URL                 = "Url"
    let CONTACT_NO          = "ContactNo";
    let SPLASH_IMAGE        = "SplashImage";
    let SPLASH_ID           = "SplashId";
    let TITLE               = "Title";
    let NO_VIEW             = "NoView";
    let IS_ACTIVE           = "isActive";
    let START_DATE          = "StartDate";
    let END_DATE            = "EndDate";


    var status : Bool

    var url : String
    var contactNo : String
    var splashImage : String
    var splashId : Int
    var title : String
    var numOfViews : Int
    var isActive : Bool
    var startDate : String
    var endDate : String

    init(data : NSDictionary){

        status      = data[STATUS] as! Bool;

        if (status == true) {

            if let item = data[DATA] as? [String: AnyObject] {

                url         = item[URL] as! String;
                contactNo   = item[CONTACT_NO] as! String;
                splashImage = item[SPLASH_IMAGE] as! String;
                splashId    = item[SPLASH_ID] as! Int;
                title       = item[TITLE] as! String;
                numOfViews  = item[NO_VIEW] as! Int;
                isActive    = item[IS_ACTIVE] as! Bool;
                startDate   = item[START_DATE] as! String;
                endDate     = item[END_DATE] as! String;

            }
        } else {

            url = "";
            contactNo = "";
            splashImage = "";
            splashId = -1;
            title = "";
            numOfViews = -1;
            isActive = false;
            startDate = "";
            endDate = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting below error

```
Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
```

Comment: Correct the `constant`s values for variable names in json declared in class. Json variable is `url` but constant valkue is `Url`. Correct it first and retry and let us know how it goes. It goes for all other variables of JSON make sure they are all same mentioned as constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the compiler doesn't known how to initialize your values if the `if let item = ...` condition fails.

You have your two options covered for the `status` condition, but inside the `true` branch you create a new condition which has no else branch, so the compiler complains rightly about non-initialized stored properties.

My suggestion is to *first* safely unwrap `data[DATA]` without making a new scope, then use the values.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough,

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

and clearly all of your properties are stored properties.

So you have to make sure once you initializer returned, **every single stored properties will have it's value**. It can be either nil or some value.

In your case, first of all,

```
status      = data[STATUS] as! Bool;
```

may fail, thus all the rest will not be executed.

Even though,  `status == true` may succeed, all the code that come with this condition may fail. And that's **violating** the rule that I just mentioned.

Comment: Your idea is correct but in this case `status` is *forced unwrapped*, telling the compiler "I swear there will be a value". The compiler is happy to comply but of course the app will crash at runtime if the value is nil.